# ReactJS - proper way to fetch data and send to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Home component, who fetch data from an API and them send the data to my modal component. In this modal component, I will use this data to fill a form.

The problem is, in my modal I can console.log the object that is coming from my Home component, but my inputs are not getting the data, they are empty.

Its like when my Home component is rendered, even though I didn't click to open my modal,
my Home component is sending the empty object to my Modal component.

I'm fairly new to React, so any tips would be appreciated.

**My Home component** (did some editing because the code was too big):

```
export default function Home() {
  const token = useSelector(state => state.auth.token)

  const [community, setCommunity] = useState([])
  const [showModalEditCommunity, setShowModalEditCommunity] = useState(false)

  function handleCloseModalEditCommunity() {
    setShowModalEditCommunity(false)
  }

  function handleShowModalEditCommunity() {
    setShowModalEditCommunity(true)
  }

  // fetching data and then saving the response into my community state
  useEffect(() => {
    const getCommunityInformations = async () => {
      const options = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token,
        }
      }
      try {
        const result = await axios(
          "https://sandbox.herokuapp.com/community/38", options
        )
        setCommunityProducts(result.data)

      } catch (error) {
        toast.error('Failed to fetch data from the server')
      }
    }
    getCommunityInformations()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container fluid as="section">
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <S.InviteSponsorSection>
            <div className="d-flex flex-column">
              <p className="title">Your community can do much more!</p>  
            </div>
             <ProfileButton
                backgroundColor="#27b8fe"
                image="/icons/edit.png"
                onClick={handleShowModalEditCommunity}
              />
            // my modal and the data I'm sending
            <ModalEditCommunity
              handleCloseModal={handleCloseModalEditCommunity}
              showModal={showModalEditCommunity}
              community={community}
            />
          </S.InviteSponsorSection>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

**My Modal component**

```
export default function ModalEditCommunity({ handleCloseModal, showModal, community }) {

  // first two console.log gives me an empty array, because I'm in my Home component, but when
  // I click to open the modal, this console.log show the exact object that is coming from my 
  // Home component, but all the inputs are empty

  console.log('community', community)

  const [name, setName] = useState(community.name)
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(community.description)
  const [facebookPage, setFacebookPage] = useState(community.facebook)

  return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <TextField
         variant="outlined"
         fullWidth={true}
         name="name"
         type="text"
         value={name}
         onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
       />
       <TextField
         fullWidth={true}
         variant="outlined"
         name="description"
         multiline
         rows="2"
         value={description}
         onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}
       />
       <TextField
         variant="outlined"
         fullWidth={true}
         name="facebookPage"
         type="text"
         value={facebookPage}
         onChange={e => setFacebookPage(e.target.value)}
        />
   </form>
  )
```

Comment: You have passed your community object as property to your ModalEditCommunity component. So it should be accessible with this.props.community inside your ModalEditCommunity component!

Comment: If you want us to help you, try to get rid of the other components and provide a code with only the two components: Home and Modal.

Comment: Hey @Kingalione functional components can't use "this"

Comment: @Meziane what other components? Home and Modal components code are already there, I don't know what you mean

Comment: Your problem has been solved: you have accepted an answer. very nice.
I meant make the code as short as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't execute your code because of too many changes to try it, but I believe the problem comes from the lifecycle.

Let's analyse the app step by step:

1. Home loads, states are initialized, XHR call is trigerred, first render is made.
   In this first render, ModalEditCommunity is already rendered, but with empty props.
2. In ModalEditCommunity, first render is triggered. **The component initializes its state with empty values**, since the XHR call is not finished yet.
3. XHR call returns. The Home component updates its state. This triggers a new render. Structures stays the same, but props change.
4. In ModalEditCommunity, the state has already been initialized. Its values are the ones used in the rendering part. So it doesn't change.

### How to solve it

Make sure you don't render the Modal unless you have the data. This way, at first render, the state will be initialized correctly.

Something like this:

```
{showModalEditCommunity && (<ModalEditCommunity
     handleCloseModal={handleCloseModalEditCommunity}
     showModal={showModalEditCommunity}
     community={community}
/>)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation, my problem is solved